# How to start kodi at startup automatically?

Tags: kodi

On my rpi4b I have installed Kodi, and added `kodi.service` to `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/systemd/system# cat kodi.service 
[Unit]
Description = Kodi media center
After=remote-fs.target systemd-user-sessions.service network-online.target nss-lookup.target sound.target bluetooth.target polkit.service upower.service mysqld.service
Wants=network-online.target polkit.service upower.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi --standalone
Restart=always
StandartInput=tty
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

When I reboot rpi4, I see login prompt (no GUI here, only CLI). I can login, everything works as expected.

I connect via ssh, and enable kodi at startup with `systemctl enable kodi`, this command does not print anything and exits with code 0.
Then, type `systemctl start kodi` -> kodi starts, everything works as expected.

Since I enabled kodi service, I expect it to start after reboot, but what I actually see is login prompt (no GUI).

This is what I see when type `systemctl status kodi` after login:

```
● kodi.service - Kodi media center
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kodi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care to have a kodi running when the raspberry starts, instead of make a service you could use the simpler 'crontab' method mentioned in the [wiki](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux#Configure_Kodi_to_autostart)

Edit the crontab:

`crontab -e`

Add:

`@reboot kodi --standalone`

just that.

Note that if you use the root crontab (ie: `sudo crontab -e`) kodi will get his settings fron the root user, and will be a different config that you see when you start it from the pi normal user.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in your Unit file. Please correct `StandartInput=tty` to `StandardInput=tty`. Then I do not understand why do you use this setting. According to `man systemd.exec` it is said:

> If tty is selected, standard input is connected to a TTY (as configured by TTYPath=, see below) and the executed process becomes the controlling process of the terminal. If the terminal is already being controlled by another process, the executed process waits until the current controlling process releases the terminal.

I do not understand this completely in your context but there are strong indicators that this could make your problems. Try without setting `StandardInput=tty`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a repo to share my **systemd unit** that works for me so far:

https://github.com/brunetton/kodi_systemd/

This could probably be improved, to cover most cases, but this works. It have the bug advantage over crontab to watch process and **restart kodi when it crashes** (thanks to the `Restart=always` directive)